# Does AWS Serverless image handler store the derivatives?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, thumbor

I've deployed the AWS Cloud formation [Serverless image handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/template.html) to resize images in an S3 bucket which is working well. It is using Cloudfront, API Gateway, Lamdba, and a custom domain.

I'm looking at the requests coming out of the Lambda function and it looks to me like every resized image is regenerated nearly every time. I'm guessing they're cached by the Cloudfront distribution for a short period of time. I presume this is how the Cloudformation was designed.

This means that I'm generating more calls to the Lambda function than is strictly necessary. When I've done this myself in the past I've saved the derivatives back to S3 so that Lambda is never called for that size again. This caused it's own problems when an original image was updated at S3 as the derivatives weren't regenerated.

Ideally what I'd like to do is either; have derivatives returned to S3; or have the cache expiry at CF to never expire and then manually call flush on updated paths. Are either of these possible with the current design? Which would be more appropriate for serving images to a media heavy website?

Comment: I've read a thread on the AWS forums that seems to indicate that the Thumbor parameters `TC_AWS_RESULT_STORAGE_BUCKET` and `TC_AWS_RESULT_STORAGE_ROOT_PATH` might configure this behaviour. However I've added them without success. Anyone had success with these?

Comment: did you see that "When tc_aws.result_storages.s3_storage is enabled." but I don't know where to edit the code :D

Comment: Ok, if you download the Lambda deployment package archive and browse to the folder /image-handler/ you see a thumbor.conf-file. There are these settings. 

Then you can modify the file and upload the whole archive back to the Lambda. However, I'll see an error that says "ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$""

Comment: Hello, I need to deal with the task to save edited images to S3. I've done [customized version](https://github.com/domino2/serverless-image-handler/commit/63c82e213c5f31bfa8b6d1bbe7eeee374dd62ced) of `awslabs/serverless-image-handler` with updated lambda function and CloudFormation template from the AWS doc what I applied too. But even no error happened, images are not recorded to S3. I was thinkig that it could be a security issue, but I've allowed `Allow: s3:PutObject`. 
If you check the code, `image-handler.js:recordEditedImage` is called as expected, but callback of putObject not.

Comment: I just found an answer for my self. I didn't know that if the params object passing to the `s3.putObject(params, callback)` function where params is a json containing _ACL_ key set to _public-read_ need to have specific aws permissions `Allow: s3:PutObject`, `Allow: s3:PutObjectAcl`.